# running multiple urg_nodes from launch file failed

Tags: ros, roslaunch, urg-node, ros-kinetic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am running trying to run two Hukoyu lidars in a roslaunch file but it fails saying:

```
[ERROR] [1594981489.035509505]: Error connecting to Hokuyo: Could not open serial Hokuyo:
/dev/ttyACM0 @ 115200
could not open serial device.
```

But both of the sensors are connected which I can verify by running:

```
rosrun urg_node urg_node _ip_address:=192.168.131.15
[ INFO] [1594981672.086954627]: Connected to network device with intensity and ID: H1866449
[ INFO] [1594981672.131274440]: Streaming data.
```

Here is my `laser.launch`

```
<launch>

  <arg name="_ip_address"/>
  <node name="urg_node" 
        pkg="urg_node" 
        type="urg_node" 
        args="$(arg _ip_address)"
        >
  </node>

</launch>
```

and here is the `lasers.launch` file:

```
<launch>

  <include ns="front_laser" file="$(find mbs_lasers)/launch/laser.launch">
    <arg name="_ip_address" value="192.168.131.15" />
  </include>

  <include ns="rare_laser" file="$(find mbs_lasers)/launch/laser.launch">
    <arg name="_ip_address" value="192.168.131.20" />
  </include>

</launch>
```

I have seen a lot of questions on [answers.ros.org](http://answers.ros.org), and checked several but the problem stays the same. I am not able to figure out where I am making a mistake. Any insights on it will be really appreciated.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/357459/running-multiple-urg_nodes-from-launch-file-failed/) by [Tahir M.](https://answers.ros.org/users/23517/tahir-m./) on ROS Answers with karma: 213 on 2020-07-17

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I was able to solve the problem by removing **_** in the ip address and `ip_address` as  `param`

```
<launch>

  <group ns="left">
    <node name="urg_node" pkg="urg_node" type="urg_node" output="screen">
      <param name="ip_address" value="192.168.0.9"/>

      <!-- <param name="serial_port" value="/dev/ttyACM0"/>
      <param name="serial_baud" value="115200"/> -->
      <param name="frame_id" value="laser"/>
      <param name="calibrate_time" value="false"/>
      <param name="publish_intensity" value="true"/>
      <param name="publish_multiecho" value="false"/>
      <param name="angle_min" value="-1.5707963"/>
      <param name="angle_max" value="1.5707963"/>
      <!-- <remap from="scan" to="front_scan"/> -->
    </node>
  </group>

  <group ns="right">
    <node name="urg_node" pkg="urg_node" type="urg_node" output="screen">
      <param name="ip_address" value="192.168.0.10"/>
      <!-- <param name="serial_port" value="/dev/ttyACM1"/>
      <param name="serial_baud" value="115200"/> -->
      <param name="frame_id" value="laser"/>
      <param name="calibrate_time" value="false"/>
      <param name="publish_intensity" value="true"/>
      <param name="publish_multiecho" value="false"/>
      <param name="angle_min" value="-1.5707963"/>
      <param name="angle_max" value="1.5707963"/>
      <!-- <remap from="scan" to="rare_scan"/> -->
    </node>
  </group>

</launch>
```

---

Originally posted by [Tahir M.](https://answers.ros.org/users/23517/tahir-m./) with karma: 213 on 2020-07-17

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0